# Python checking datetime overlapping in list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I've list of dictionary format like below

```
[{'end': '19:00', 'start': '10:00'}, {'end': '23:00', 'start': '12:15'}, {'end': '12:00', 'start': '09:15'}]
```

and want to check is time interval is overlapping or not

What I'm planning to do:

1. First want to sort the list of dictionary based on start value
2. Comparing second item start value with first item end value

So, my current approach is:

```
for elem,next_elem in zip(sorted_slot, sorted_slot[1:]):
    print(datetime.strptime(elem['end'], '%H:%M') > datetime.strptime(next_elem['start'], '%H:%M'))
```

Am I in right approach?

Comment: Are you comparing just first two intervals? Because if not, you need to check every pair. I don't see any point in sorting intervals here. Another problem are interval lengths - can it be zero? And another problem: as it stands you will need to add some extra logic/assumptions for intervals that cross midnight.

Comment: Agree with @jurez. Please define "is overlapping between 3 intervals or not" (there 3 in your examples).

Comment: Yes, It can be single or multiple. If multiple then comparing will be there. I've updated my ques.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be depended on your input meaning.
If every element is the time interval of itself (for every element, the time interval starts at its start value and ends at its end value), you want first  to:

1. sort the list of dictionary based on start value.
2. Comparing every item start value with its previous item end value. If the start value of element x is smaller than the end value of element x-1, there is overlapping.

Otherwise, if your values ordered like chain (every time interval starts at start value of element x and ends at end value of element x+1), I think it will be much easier for you to first order the values like in the first section and then go by the algorithm to check the overlaps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string as time to time and make condition

```
import datetime
def checkTime(newTime):
    newTimeObj=datetime.datetime.strptime(newTime, '%H:%M').time()
    lst=[{'end': '19:00', 'start': '10:00'}, {'end': '23:00', 'start': '12:15'}, {'end': '12:00', 'start': '09:15'}]
    x=0
    for i in lst:
        timeStart=datetime.datetime.strptime(i["start"], '%H:%M').time()
        print(timeStart)
        timeEnd=datetime.datetime.strptime(i["end"], '%H:%M').time()
        if newTimeObj>timeStart and newTimeObj<timeEnd:
            return True,x
        x+=1
    return False,-1
exist,index=checkTime("23:30")
print(exist)
print(index)
print("--")
exist,index=checkTime("20:30")
print(exist)
print(index)

10:00:00
12:15:00
09:15:00
False
-1
--
10:00:00
12:15:00
True
1
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to improve your code is to convert the `start` and `end` times to `datetime` objects when the slots are first created, instead of doing so each time when calling for a check.
After that you can then sort slots base on `start` dates.

```py
def check_overlap(slots):
    for slot in slots:
        slot['start'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(slot['start'], '%H:%M')
        slot['end'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(slot['end'], '%H:%M')

    slots = sorted(slots, key=lambda x: x['start'])
    return any(elem['end'] > next_elem['start']
               for elem, next_elem in zip(slots, slots[1:]))

slots = [{'end': '19:00', 'start': '10:00'}, {'end': '23:00', 'start': '12:15'}, {'end': '12:00', 'start': '09:15'}]
print(check_overlap(slots))
```